# Symfony 3 FOS Rest return login page

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I have a symfony web app. I want add feature to my web app, that is restful API.

so restful api and web app, run in one web application / project.

I finally success set rule for API and web, but the problem is if I access in browser, it will return to login page, and I need to login 1st. Its no problem, the problem is, when I test in postman or client app. The client cant get the data because it return login page.

this is my config.yml :

```
# Nelmio CORS Configuration
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false

# FOSRest Configuration
fos_rest:
    body_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['text/html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
```

This is my security.yml

```
# To get started with security, check out the documentation:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: 
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/local_registration, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

This is my controller :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use AppBundle\Entity\User;

class DemoController extends FOSRestController
{

    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/api/demo")
     */
    public function getAction()
    {
        $data = array("hello" => "world");
        // $view = $this->view($data);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**the problem**
For now when I get localhost:8000/api/demo with browser, I just login and I get the data in JSON, but when I access with postman, return is login page HTML

how to login with api? or make it not return login page, but still authenticated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that your Symfony retrieve the user's session with a cookie of session. 
So when you do the call to your API from the browser you are already authenticated.

But in Postman the cookie aren't shared from Google Chrome (yes you have to use Google Chrome with postman) by default, for that you have to activate the **postman interceptor**. After that postman will do his HTTP calls with the same cookies of Google Chrome on the given domain.

A good (and open source) http client is **Insomnia**, you may want to let it a try :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some other authentication systems for the restful part of your app. [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) can be good choice for it.

Generally, you will add `Authentication` header to your request with `Bearer` cryptic token, and let the bundle do the rest.